# Increments of sublinear functions vanish

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(n)/n\longrightarrow 0$. This is just a thought, but I think it is possible to show that then, $f(n+1)-f(n)\longrightarrow 0$ follows. However, I can only show this, if the function is assumed analytic (due to my argument exploiting the series expansion of $f(n+1)$ at $n$) or if $\varepsilon_n=f(n)/n\downarrow 0$ (by using $f(n+1)=(n+1)\varepsilon_{n+1}<n\varepsilon_n+\varepsilon_n$). Is there an argument that avoids these additional hypotheses, thus showing the result with more generality? Or perhaps it does not hold in general? Thanks for any heads up.

Comment: How about $f(n) = (-1)^{n}$

Comment: thank you you are right!